# OSI Model for Smart Meters

Tags: meter

Seeing as smart meters are becoming more and more popular (in particular countries), I would like to understand smart meters and thought knowing the OSI Model would be a good place to start. I already have a basic understanding of smart meters and the use of networks  etc. but my limited knowledge hasn't allowed me to define each layer of the OSI.

So far I've only really got two layers:

1. Application layers - define the content of the data messages and the way they're presented.
2. Physical layers - define the communications medium and methods of data communication.

Any help with separating these into physical, data link, network, transport, session, presentation and application would be brilliant.

Comment: Your question appears to be confusing a specific device and generic details about the OSI model.  Which do you actually want help with?

Comment: I'm hoping I make sense when I say I'm looking for the explicit OSI Model in relation to your average smart meter.

Comment: The OSI model doesn't change, it's a general model you can apply to many modern networking stacks.  A typical smart meter might implement something for the whole OSI model.

Comment: But can you not relate each layer to a particular aspect of a smart metering solution?

Comment: A particular implementation could merge 2 or more layers together, or even skip some entirely.

Comment: yes that's sort of what I mean. For example, which layers to smart meters merge? if any?

Comment: Different meters with different software could work completely differently, the model is just a model. In theory, reality is the same as theory...

Comment: I completely understand that different meters will have a pass through the OSI Model differently. But is there any references to the different types of meters and how they differ in terms of the OSI Model?

Answer (score 2):

The OSI model (Basic Reference Model) itself (as a set of services and protocols) is defined in the ITU-T X.200 series of publications (they are aligned with the corresponding ISO/IEC standards) which are publicly available (search www.itu.int).

As for smart meters, there are several methods based on the ISO modeling approach.  I know DLMS/COSEM (IEC 62056 series), so called "Digital Substation" (IEC 61850 series), TASE/TASE.2 telecontrol (IEC 60870 parts).  May be other exist.

If that is your research interest, i recommend you to take a look on ANSI C19.xx series protocols.  They are not ISO based, but technically they are much more perfect than any ISO based attempt.

In practice, proprietary protocols rules now...

Comment: I do not agree on the last sentence:

In practice IEC-61850 gets more and more important, as new facilities neatly integrate the model, especially in countries that haven't had a lot of automated power facilities until now: India, China.. 

Recognize that the Electricity-Industry lives by very slow standards. IEC-61850 was finished almost 15 years ago - and is now starting to become the to-be-standard.